# Android: how can you determine the actual mobile carrier name?

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I have an app that tries to determine the quality of the mobile network in various locations, and then associate it with which network is in use on the phone.

To get the mobile carrier, I am using

```
TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager)mContext.getSystemService(
  Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String carrierName = manager.getNetworkOperatorName();
```

This generally works, but in some cases, I get the result, "Fi Network".  Since Google Fi switches between T-Mobile, Sprint and US Celluar in the United States, I'd like to know which of the actual carriers is used, so I can use it to determine the quality of the network.

Is there any API that can tell me which of these carriers the phone is actually using?

Comment: I think to get that information, you need to return the "tower" information, not the "Carrier" information.  since Fi is a tethering between those services, i believe you need the Tower information

Comment: Makes sense.  So the obvious follow-up is what is the Android API to get this?  I am not finding it.

Comment: have you tried `TelephonyManager.getSimOperator()`? it should return `MCC` & `MNC` codes which should uniquely identify a carrier, but I'm not sure how it works with `Fi`

Comment: Interesting idea on `getSimOperator()`.  I see that it returns a numeric identifier encoded as a String.  For my T-Mobile carrier in the US, I get 310260, which you can look up from here:  http://www.imei.info/operator-codes/.  I am not sure what it will return in this field for "Fi Network", since I do not have that carrier, so I'll have to put it in the next app version, and see if it returns something useful for that case.  I do note that "Fi Network" does  not appear in that online list, nor does the string "Fi" by itself in any form.

Comment: That works!  I had to add my own lookup table to convert known operator codes to carrier names.  So for "Fi Network" I saw a case that returned a getSimOperator() of 310260, so I convert this to the following string: "Fi Network: T-Mobile: 310260"

Comment: @marmor If you can convert your comment to an Answer, I'll accept it so other folks can find this solution more easily.

Comment: sure, converted to an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`TelephonyManager.getSimOperator()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getSimOperator()) will return [MCC & MNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_country_code) codes which should uniquely identify a carrier, you can easily find lists online that maps MCC+MNC to operators names.

Comment: This worked for me to identify if a Fi Network subscriber was using T-Mobile or Sprint, using these hard-coded lookups:  `String[] sprintCodes = {"310120"};  String[] tMobileCodes = {"310026","310160","310200","310210","310220","310230","310240","310250","310260","310270","310280","310290","310310","310330","310580","310660","310800"};`